# footer stuck at mid page despite body height 100%

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

[live site](http://erintrimble.com/about/)

My footer is getting stuck mid page on certain pages(about, contact) despite having set body `height:100%`. I've specified footer height, and have tried `position:fixed`, `position:absolute`, and `bottom:0`. Nothing seems to help, any ideas?

Edit: Attempting "Sticky Footer" does not work either; it places the footer slightly to the right of center page.

```
body {
    background: #fff;;
    font-family: london, Arial, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 0 120px 60px;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 340px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: You want your footer at the bottom right? Position fixed or absolute seem t do just fine, unless you're overwriting it somewhere.

Comment: Neither of the position options have worked for me, and aside from floats(which I've tried clearing) I have no other specifically positioned elements.

Comment: I try this with your source and it works: <style type="text/css"> #footer { position: fixed; bottom: 0; background-color: black;}</style> just above body. What browser are you testing it?

Comment: I've tried both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Do you want the footer to be 'stuck' to the bottom of the window even if the content overflows the window? Or do you want the footer to be after the end of the content?

Comment: @Ben, I want the footer to be at the end of the content but not mid-page if the page has limited content.

Answer (score 0):

Add 100% height to your container, fiddle and code below

http://jsfiddle.net/pJAsF/2/

```
html, body {
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    height:100%;
}
#header {
    position:relative;
    background:#333;
    min-height:50px;
}
#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:100%;
}
#container p {
    font:2em normal Futura, sans-serif;
}
#footer {
    background-color:#333;
    min-height:50px;
}

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="container">
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: I'm confused - there is quite clearly content in the home and contact pages? Also, how else can I present the footer if not with `#footer`? Please clarify, thank you.